# How to pass prop from one component to another?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I need to pass prop called name from one React component to another, but something goes wrong. Could you tell me how to do it right?

Thanks in advance

```
import React from 'react';

export class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello World and {this.props.name}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Greeting from './Greeting';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Greeting name='Alex' />;
      <h2> Welcome, {Greetings.props.name} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `Greetings.props.name` is not a static value, you cant reference it like so, please refer to basic React tutorial. In this case you know the literal value "Alex" so you shouldnt reference it.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components

Comment: Here is a better WIP docs version: https://beta.reactjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

two things:

1. looks like you are mixing class and functional components, i recommend going for functional as its more common now. in that case the Greeting will look like this:

```
export function Greeting(props) {
  return (
    <h1>Hello World and {props.name}</h1>
  )
}
```

2. you are passing the prop the the  component, but you cant access it from its parent. you can create another variable for that:

```
const greetingName = "Alex";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Greeting name={greetingName} />;
      <h2> Welcome, {greetingName} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## In Greeting.js you have missed parameter

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Greeting from './Greeting';

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  return (
    <div>
      <Greeting name="Alex" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Greeting.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Greeting = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World and My name is {props.name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Greeting
```

Comment: `this.props.name` is correct when using a React.Component, so that's not the issue. Also `name` doesn't have to be in the useState.

Comment: Make few changes and it will work